# Global Dispatcher in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have some WP7 code that looks like this:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

public static class GlobalDispatcher
{
    public static Dispatcher Current { get { return Deployment.Current.Dispatcher; } }
}
```

What is the equivalent in WinRT?  Is there no globally accessible Dispatcher (or CoreDispatcher) object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to use `Window.Current.Dispatcher`.

Comment: Thank you Jeff!  Note to anyone else looking for this, it is Window.Current.Dispatcher

Answer (score 6):

Just adding this as answer, as it better solves the problem in my opinion:

Window.Current is null if the application is not focused and thus will bring you in trouble when there is a user involved ;)

> CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher isn't null...
>
> –  Jeremy White Aug 4 '13 at 13:09

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
        var dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            try
            {
               //Your code here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleException(ex);
            }
        });
```