# Checking internet connectivity in Windows8 via C# fails

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to test the Internet connection in Windows8 from my C# application. I have a variable of type Boolean that returns me the connection status. When the boolean is true: do nothing. When the boolean becomes false, load my "`NetworkDisconection`" page. However, when I debug this line:

```
if (this.Frame != null)
```

I get an exception:

> *The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))*

Yeah, this  method is on a different thread. How can I resolve this?

```
private bool bConection;

public HUB()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        bConection = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile()!= null;
        NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged;
    }

    void NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged(object sender)
    {

        if (NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile() == null)
        {
            if (bConection == false)
            {
                bConection = true;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            if (bConection == true)
            {
                bConection = false;

                if (this.Frame != null)
                {
                    Frame.Navigate(typeof(NetworkDisconection));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type of project is this? WPF, Winforms, ?

Comment: No, WindowsStore (Windows 8)

Comment: ok, i added that tag so it will be easier for people to help. I'm not familiar with windows store apps, but maybe this will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579027/run-code-on-ui-thread-in-winrt - From the UI thread you access and store the Dispatcher `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;` which you can then use to run actions from background threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code and it should fix your problem...

```
  Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                if (this.Frame != null)
                {
                    Frame.Navigate(typeof(NetworkDisconection));
                }
            });
```

You should be able to acquire the Dispatcher directly since it looks like your code is in the code-behind of a XAML page (reference to this.Frame).

Tons of good info can be found in the C[# Win8 Dev Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/threads).  Search for Dispatcher and you will find several discussions on it.  As always, check out [GenApp](http://aka.ms/30Days) for other great resources.

Answer (score 0):

The `NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged` event is raised on a **non-UI thread**. Similar to *WinForms* and *WPF*, you are still limited to accessing controls on the UI thread.

To get around this aspect, you'll have to invoke the UI thread similar to how you would on *WinForms* or *WPF* using `this.Invoke`/`this.Dispatcher.Invoke`.

At first you may try to use `Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync()` but you will notice that `Window.Current` is always `null` here.

Instead, you should use `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync()` in the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core` namespace. Yeah, that's quite a mouthful for sure so I recommend this helper method in *App.cs*.

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.UI.Core;

public static IAsyncAction ExecuteOnUIThread(DispatchedHandler action)
{
  var priority = CoreDispatcherPriority.High;
  var dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;

  return dispatcher.RunAsync(priority, action);
}
```

I would also recommend this helper method too:

```
public static bool CheckInternetAccess()
{
  var profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

  if (profile == null) return false;

  var connectivityLevel = profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel();
  return connectivityLevel.HasFlag(NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
}
```

And finally:

```
async void NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged(object sender)
{
  var isConnected = CheckInternetAccess();

  await ExecuteOnUIThread(() =>
  {        
    if (!isConnected && this.Frame != null)
      this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ConnectionLostPage));
  });
}
```