# Call C# method from C++/CX code

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I've already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434874/calling-c-sharp-method-from-c-code-in-wp8) but in my case I have native only Direct X project. Can I call C# method from C++/CX in such case?

Comment: i don't see why not if its a WinRT assembly.

Comment: @DanielA.White i don't understand. Can I call C# code from C++-WinRT directly? can I see example?

Comment: try reading this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx

Comment: @DanielA.White i've already read it, but it is for Windows Store apps, not for WP8. There is no any WP8 WinRT template in my VS2012...

Comment: try reading this one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714080(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: it does not look like its supported at this time.