# how to get windows phone 8 OS version using cpp

Tags: windows-phone-8

cpp has no namespace
System.Environment.OSVersion

so what's the api to get the OSVersion?

and system api GetVersion GetVersionEx seem not enabled in wp8

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot missing when you go from Windows 8 to WP8. The only way I found to get all your problems solved is to call C# code from C++/CX. Here's how : [Calling C# method from C++ code in WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434874/calling-c-sharp-method-from-c-code-in-wp8/16127627#16127627)

Comment: There's no native API for a lot of things in WP8, or even Windows 8. I had an issue with getting the available memory for an app with no native API. There's also no native access to the UI classes in WP8. I assume they were either trying to cut the code size to fit low memory deivces OR they were lazy and didn't finish the WP8 port in time :).

Comment: the thread your methoded seems a way for “C# project with a Cpp dll can using C#”.
but in my situation. it is a Cpp project to call C# dll, ths diffierece is I can't init c# dll. I can't load C# dll, so I can't call func SetCallback.
so it is not suitable for me.

Comment: Well, the thing is that you'll have to create a C# project and make that your app's entry point (and reference the C++ project from it). You can't do that from a purely native C++ project. A big hustle, I know, but there isn't any other way.