# How to solve this E_POINTER (NullPointerException) when I attempt to invoke a callback through a WinRT object from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

goto the 'PROBLEM' label if you don't want to read the background.

I first posted this question in an attempt to find a way to invoke functions from C++ into C#: [How does one make function calls or trigger events from a Native component into a C#/XAML component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304386/how-does-one-make-function-calls-or-trigger-events-from-a-native-component-into)

This lead to the solution which was marked as the answer, which I had confirmed to work by a friend off of stack overflow.

I then implemented the two following callback classes as per the solution's instruction:

```
// C++ land
// This is the interface that defines all of the functions
// that this component can call on the C#/xaml side
[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
public interface class ICallback
{
public:
    // begins the displaying of the progress bar and signals
    // the start of a new task
    virtual void BeginProgress(Platform::String ^ message);

    // completes a the progress started by the progress bar and returns the
    // result of the task done. Also has an optional message which can give
    // the user additional information if failure occured.
    virtual void CompleteProgress(int result, Platform::String ^ message);
};

// C# land
// used as a callback from the native component to here
// just delegates calls to the page
class Callback : ICallback
{
    // a reference to the page so we can dispatch UI events
    private ViewerPage m_page;

    public Callback(ViewerPage page)
    {
        m_page = page;
    }

    // just delegates to the page
    public void BeginProgress(String message)
    {
        m_page.BeginProgress(message);
    }

    public void CompleteProgress(int result, String message)
    {
        m_page.CompleteProgress(result, message);
    }
}
// the page then handles those calls as you would expect
```

PROBLEM:

I set the callback when the native component is initialized like so:

```
// ViewerPage.cs
private void DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        if (m_d3dBackground == null)
        {
            m_d3dBackground = new Direct3DBackground();

            // Set window bounds in dips
            m_d3dBackground.WindowBounds = new Windows.Foundation.Size(
                (float)Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth,
                (float)Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight
                );

            ... // more initialization stuff

            // hook up the callback
            m_d3dBackground.Callback = m_callback;

            ... // even more

        }
}
```

I then pass the callback from the m_d3dBackground to the Renderer class like so:

```
m_renderer->Initialize(Callback);
```

The renderer then attempts to invoke the callback when appropriate, like so:

```
// let the user know we're starting the lengthiest one time operation of this application
// TODO: figure out the bug that keeps this from working
m_callback->BeginProgress("Loading Model");
```

This is when things go wrong.

[image: Exception]

I get a Platform::NullReferenceException. I can confirm that the pointer that is invoked is still the first pointer that was passed into the d3dBackground object.

Here is a stack trace at the time of the exception:

[image: Stack Trace]

Unforunately, most of the records are concurrency gibberish, so that's not much help.

Here are the member variables, including the m_callback that is so problematic:

[image: Member Variables]

Lastly, here's a memory dump of the location where the NullPointerException occurred (the exact location is highlighted):

[image: Memory]

I'm really scratching my head over this one, so if anyone has any intuition or hints I would greatly appreciate them.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it approximately 3 minutes after hitting submit on this essay.

The problem was that the C# version of the callback object did not look %100 like what the C++ compiler thought it looked like (as per ICallback's definition).

The problem? The reference to ViewerPage was in the same memory location as where the compiler thought BeginProgress() was.

The solution? Move the ICallback implementation into the Page class because the compiler automatically moves member variables to the start of the object regardless of their location in code.

```
public partial class ViewerPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Callback m_callback;

    ... // rest of ViewPage class

    // used as a callback from the native component to here
    // just delegates calls to the page
    class Callback : ICallback
    {
        public Callback()
        {
        }

        // just delegates to the page
        public void BeginProgress(String message)
        {
            BeginProgress(message);
        }

        public void CompleteProgress(int result, String message)
        {
            CompleteProgress(result, message);
        }
    }
}
```

-.-

Comment: I'm actually reading that book right now. I've only just finished chapter 2 though, so I haven't reached that drop of wisdom yet.