# Call C# from C++ in a windows phone 8.0 solution

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am trying to call C# code in a Cocos2d-x application (windows phone part).

I have add to my solution a Windows Phone Runtime Component to do this but in my C# project, i cannot implement an interface which is define the Windows Runtime Component project.

I followed this thread without success : [Calling C# method from C++ code in WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434874/calling-c-sharp-method-from-c-code-in-wp8)

Some code of my solution :

The interface in the windows phone runtime component which i'm trying to implement through a c# class

```
namespace WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent
{
    [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
    public interface class ICallback
    {
    public:
         virtual void Exec( Platform::String ^Command, Platform::String ^Param);
    };
}
```

The c# class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Runtime;
using WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent;

namespace cocos2d
{
    class CallbackImpl : ICallback // Here is the problem
    {

    }
}
```

In the C# class from the C# project, i can reference the windows runtime component calling "using WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent;" but when i trying to call something from the namespace, or when i type "WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent::something" there is nothing after "::".

Comment: `Here is the problem` - and the problem is? Exception, compiler error?

Comment: Sorry, the compiler error is : "the type ou the name 'ICallback is not found (missing using directive or assembly is missing'.