# WinRT C++/CX to C# multithread marshaling

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, marshalling, c++-cx

So we are working on new app for Windows Store and we're utilizing DirectX on C++/CX part of app and C# on other. As we needed some sort of communication, we created interface in shared library (C#) and class that implements it on C# side of the project. We then pass instance of that class to the C++. When C++ need to communicate with c#, it calls methods from shared interface and c# executes what was implemented in the class.

The problem arises when C++ calls methods from another thread than then object was passed on to it. Error:

`The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.`

Here's how it works:

```
C#                  instance of shared interface (some class)

C# -> C++           \/ passed in parameter of public C++ method

C++                 saves to variable
C++                 creates new thread
C++                 calls instance->SayHello();          

C#                  exception
```

Shared interface: (C#)

```
public interface IUserMessageService
{
    void WriteMessage(string message, MessageTypes type);
}
```

Implementation: (C#)

```
public sealed class UserMessageService : IUserMessageService
{ ... }
```

Assign method (C++)

```
void AssignUserMessageService(...::IUserMessageService ^service) { m_service = service; }
```

I then call `AssignUserMessageService` with instance of `UserMessageService` from UI thread. Error occurs when I try to access data passed by C++ when calling `WriteMessage` in another thread.

Is there any other way to pass instance or call method?

Comment: this might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341591/the-application-called-an-interface-that-was-marshalled-for-a-different-thread

Comment: @Matt that actually worked for me. The error was that I was using `CoreApplication.MainWindow.CoreWindow.Dispatcher` which look like isn't UI thread dispatcher...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `CoreApplication.MainWindow.CoreWindow.Dispatcher` instead of `Window.Current.Dispatcher`