# Timer in UWP App which isn't linked to the UI

Tags: c#, timer, uwp

I'm working on an UWP MVVM project and would like to implement an automatic logout system if the user interaction stops for a specific time.
Until now I'm using a `DispatcherTimer` to count backwards from 200 every second.

```
TimerLeave = 200;
var _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
_dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
_dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

_dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

But because the DispatcherTimer is linked
with the UI and I'm building a MVVM App,  I'm looking for an alternative.
I searched a bit and found [Run a background task on a timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186458.aspx). The problem is
that this timer can only be set to run every 15 minutes, which is a little too long to automaticly logout a user in my case. I found no workaround to reduce the 15 minutes.
So my question is, is there any possibility to set up a timer in an UWP Project that isn't linked to the UI and can be set variable?

Comment: did you check this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer) ?

Comment: @AntonioUgraalBarile I totally missed System.Threading.Timer, thank you for this hint. I've only found System.Timer and this one isn't supported in UWP Apps.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes - you can for example use [Timer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) - though you must remember that it run on separate thread. Example:

```
private Timer timer;
public MainPage()
{        
    this.InitializeComponent();
    timer = new Timer(timerCallback, null, (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
}

private async void timerCallback(object state)
{
    // do some work not connected with UI

    await Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () => {
            // do some work on UI here;
        });
}
```

Note that the work dispatched on UI dispatcher may not be processed right away - it depend on dispatcher's workload.

Also remember that this timer runs along with your app and won't work when app is suspended.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: This threw a null reference exception, while https://stackoverflow.com/a/27698035/118153 worked for me.

Comment: @Iiridayn It's only a way of getting dispatcher, you may also get it different ways. Just a matter of being sure that you are able to access it.

Answer (score 12):

I resolved this issue recently using a [ThreadPoolTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer.aspx) class.

```
ThreadPoolTimer timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((t) =>
        {
            //do some work \ dispatch to UI thread as needed
        }, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

At present I am not aware of any advantage of this over the Timer solution already posted, but it has functioned well.

Comment: Tested both solutions.ThreadPoolTimer is more accurate than Timer. Will use it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be right at your code but I have used threadpool timer instead of dispacher timer,
after referring above blog.

If I talk about initial level I was using dispatcher timer for my app, what happens actually, it goes hang after every 2days of continuous standby.
So I thought of threadpool timer as you are referring in this blog, but in threadpool it went hung in just 5-6 hours.

So as per my experience I think dispatcher timer is more preferable than threadpool timer.

It's just my experience of using it.

Comment: Can you turn this into an answer to the question at the top of this page? This is not a blog, it is a Q/A community. So you are supposed to answer questions when you start typing into the appropriatly labeled "Your Answer" field.