# Refreshing time regularly in c#

Tags: c#, uwp

How do I observe the time regularly as it changes? I tried the simple thing by implanting time check at every second but that slowed the program and constantly hung up the buttons. How do I do it without hanging up the program?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your code?

Comment: By executing the check in another thread.

Comment: What do you mean by observing time: You need to know how much time has passed since something? You need to perform an operation every X? You need to update something when something happens asap?

Comment: @3615 its like I have to perform an operation every X.

Comment: Then you would need to use a **Timer** (not sure which one to use for UWP). Timer allows you to execute operation every X. Check this answer to see an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34271284/5246145) @Gaurab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can use dispatcher timer. Here is an example implementation in UWP:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private DispatcherTimer timer;
        private int counter = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();

            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (counter == 10)
            {
                //do operation in every 10 seconds
                counter = 0;
                //if you want to stop the timer use timer.Start()
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```