# UWP Measure Textblock DesiredSize in Background

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have a textblock with text and fontsize. I can find the desired size for the textblock using Textblock.Measure(), but this has to be done in the background. Is there a way to compute this in background (Task.Run).

Comment: what do you mean when you say background? Could you please elaborate. I do have an answer for you but based on your explanation, I'll be able to answer you more precisely.  Please share, what you want to do with the size of the textblock and what does background mean

Comment: Be specific, what is the problem if you run `Textblock.Measure` in the background? Do you encounter some kind of exception? or does this call just not return the correct desired size?

Comment: @AdityaSharma I need to compute the TextBlock's DesiredSize inside Task.Run like Task.Run(()=> var MyTextBlock = new TextBlock(); MyTextBlock.Measure()); But if I do this it will throw mashelling exception.

Comment: @kennyzx The problem is if I create a new Textblock and measure it inside Task.Run(()=>{}); It will throw mashelling exception.

Comment: mashelling exception is caused as you're trying to perform an operation that needs to be done on a UI thread in a background thread. You can solve it using a Dispatcher. You can find a solution for it [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27698035/3766231)

Comment: Yes but dispathcer will take it back to the UI thread, but I want this to happen all in another thread without disturbing the UI thread.

Comment: Now if you could please elaborate on why do you need the desired size for the textblock I could finalize an answer and provide it to you

Comment: I'm trying to create a datagrid. I want to know the maximum width a column requires. In order to compute that I want to know the desired size of all the textblocks in that particular column.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar yes, update this in the question. Provide more details like the exact exception type and message, post screenshots if necessary, and give the code. This is how to ask.