# .net Maui Comexeption raised when Connection lost

Tags: c#, maui

Im currently working on a maui project which I use for the ui of my raspberry pi.

It often disconnects and therefore I implemented a ConnectionLost event where it should clean the ui and display a alert so i can see whenever it disconnects and just connect again.

However when i try to change the ui contents I get a ComException with the message

*The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'*

Here is the C# Method

```
private async void OnConnectionLost()
{
     ReaderBtn.IsEnabled = false;
     PriorityBtn.IsEnabled = false;
     SetIp("Not connected");
     await DisplayAlert("Error","Connection Lost", "OK");    
}

 public void SetIp(string ip)
 {
     idStr.Text = ip;
     deviceStr.Text = "";
     nrStr.Text = "";
     UpdateIpColor();
 }
```

What would I have to add so the Exception will not come up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

It means that you are trying to update UI from a different (not UI) thread. For example, set text to Label or something else.

This method (if it is called on connection lost) needs to be called from [MainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/main-thread).

```
private async void OnConnectionLost()
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
       // Code to run on the main thread
       ReaderBtn.IsEnabled = false;
       PriorityBtn.IsEnabled = false;
       SetIp("Not connected");
       await DisplayAlert("Error","Connection Lost", "OK");    

     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your method `OnConnectionLost()` from the Main Thread.
I would suggest you check this article, it will help you to solve your problem.

[The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341591/the-application-called-an-interface-that-was-marshalled-for-a-different-thread)

Learn: [Create a thread on the .NET MAUI UI thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/main-thread?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-SIO.YaA2IJ8dHlItDxfpiA&epi=a1LgFw09t88-SIO.YaA2IJ8dHlItDxfpiA&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=(ir__69qppduqa9kf612ydwykgeembn2xq1fb316btiuy00)(7806)(1243925)(a1LgFw09t88-SIO.YaA2IJ8dHlItDxfpiA)()&irclickid=_69qppduqa9kf612ydwykgeembn2xq1fb316btiuy00)

**Syntax:**

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    // Code to run on the main thread
});
```