# How can i update the UI of my Windows universal app from a seperate thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, windows-10-universal

I had an alerting application on Windows 8 phone using C# and XAML. when I received a notification whilst the app was running I was able to update the UI using this code.

```
   private void PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
        {
           Textboc.text = "Something";
        });
    }
```

However I have now moved my application to Windows 10 Universal. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke does not seem to be available. Is there an alternative to this that I can use to update the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () => { // your code should be here});
```

[Correct way to get the CoreDispatcher in a Windows Store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477190/correct-way-to-get-the-coredispatcher-in-a-windows-store-app)