# UWP Dispatcher RunAsync Not Changing UI Content

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, checkbox, uwp

I'm trying to update my UWP App's UI from a non-UI thread. I'm using `Dispatcher.RunAsync` to make the changes. I have tried changing:

- `ToggleSwitch.OnContent` and `OffContent`
- `Image.Source`
- `Checkbox.IsChecked`
- `Checkbox.Content`

Nothing changes.

Currently, I'm reading values from the local settings cache (`ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings`), but I have tried using bools. No difference.

When debugging, Visual Studio indicates that the properties like `Checkbox.IsChecked`, etc. do change. However, in the app itself, no changes occur visually.

My current XAML code for the `Checkbox`es:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="200,93,0,0"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="200,125,0,0"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="200,157,0,0"/>
```

The cs code:

```
public async void updateUI()
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            // change checkBox1 UI State
            checkBox1.IsChecked = (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["test1"])) ? true : false;
            checkBox1.Content = (checkBox1.IsChecked.Value) ? "On" : "Off";

            // change checkBox2 UI State
            checkBox2.IsChecked = (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["test2"])) ? true : false;
            checkBox2.Content = (checkBox2.IsChecked.Value) ? "On" : "Off";

            // change checkBox3 UI State
            checkBox3.IsChecked = (Convert.ToBoolean(localSettings.Values["test3"])) ? true : false;
            checkBox3.Content = (checkBox3.IsChecked.Value) ? "On" : "Off";
        });
}
```

I call `updateUI` by simply invoking it, like this: `updateUI()`. And, no, there is no exception or error. Just nothing happens visually.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong??

**Edit**

I am unable to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` as it is absent in a UWP Environment.

**Edit 2**

What I've noticed is that: if I put the same code (without the `Dispatcher.RunAsync`) in a UI event like a button click event, it runs perfectly. Can't one, somehow replicate this programmatically?

I have tried simply invoking an eventhandler method (like `btnClickMe_Click`) both with and without the `Dispatcher.RunAsync` code. However, that also does not cause any visual change whatsoever.

Comment: Can you tell from where you are calling updateUI()?

Comment: I am calling it from such a method: `public async void Connection_OnRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)` which is triggered when my WinForm Component sends data to the UWP App through the `AppServices` API

Comment: As a note, an expression like `IsChecked = someBool ? true : false` could be simplified to just `IsChecked = someBool`.

Comment: Note taken, thank you @Clemens

Comment: Your question's title sounds odd. *RunAsync not working*, seriously? When you put a breakpoint somewhere in the Dispatcher Action, does it get hit?

Comment: Yes, the action gets hit, but the visuals do not change. Only the 'virtual' properties change (according to Visual Studio)

Comment: Anyone have ideas?

Comment: [Which dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16477190/60761) are you using?

Comment: And `async void` is always murky. Make it an `async Task` and do `updateUI().Wait()` in the caller - more chance to see exceptions.

Comment: So the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync` with `updateUI() .Wait()` and `async Task` respectively, throws an exception which VS "is unconfigured to catch". `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync` with `await updateUI()` does not throw an exception, however, it doesn't work either.  `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().CoreWindow.Dispatcher` with `await updateUI()` throws a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Element not found.'` exception. Testing 3rd now.

Comment: `Window.Current.Dispatcher` with `await updateUI()` throws a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Not much chance of help this way. Start writing a [mcve], a new project with just 1 checkbox. Add only the essentials.

Comment: Hi, thx for offering, however, I've figured it out. I had to run the code in a loop on a `BackgroundWorker` thread, because the `updateUI()` method was secretly throwing an exception as a result of it being called too quickly before the method could complete.

Comment: Hi @HenkHolterman, I know its a month later; however, I found that my solution isn't efficient. If you're still interested in helping me, it'll be greatly appreciated. I've uploaded a sample here: https://github.com/dilvermaak/UINotUpdatingFromDispatcher

Comment: @user9618595 is the GitHub repo updated for reproducing this issue? I can look sometime this week if you still have the issue.

Comment: Hi @saurabh,  I finally solved the problem by subscribing to the `ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged` event and calling updateUI() from there. The DataChanged event gets invoked when I call the `ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChange()` method. Thanks though.