# Dispatcher.invoke problem in a class : C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

here is  part of my code:

```
public void refreshShowCase()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        bitmapImage[i] = new BitmapImage(new Uri(posterURLCollection[i]));
        image[i] = new Image { Source = bitmapImage[i] }; //Error occurs here****
    }
}
```

when I run this I get this error: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

So I add my code inside `Disapther.Invoke`

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
   BitmapImage[] bitmapImage = new BitmapImage[14];
   Image[] image = new Image[14];

   //Do a loop for defining Bitmaps sources
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
   {
         bitmapImage[i] = new BitmapImage(new Uri(posterURLCollection[i]));
         image[i] = new Image { Source = bitmapImage[i] };
   }
}
```

Now I have this error: 'Dispatcher' doesn't exist in the current context!

How should I solve this? Please help.

**Update1:** mentioned code is inside void of a class which I have created!

Comment: Does System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke work?

Comment: @Adam: When I use that I get this: 'Current' does not exist in the type 'Application'

Comment: You get a compile time error or a runtime ?

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee: When I don't use Dispatcher I get runtime  error which I  have mentioned: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this. But when I use Dispatcher a red line goes under the `This.Dispatcher` and says:  'Dispatcher' doesn't exist in the current context!

Comment: My crystal ball says that you wrote a UWP app, not a WPF app.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477190/correct-way-to-get-the-coredispatcher-in-a-windows-store-app

Comment: @HansPassant: In app's main class this.Dispatcher works fine! this problem is for that special class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you are using `this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate` inside of a custom class. `this` refers to functions inside of that class. Your custom class does not have `Dispatcher`.

Instead use: `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate` and make sure this your custom class containing this code falls under your `App` namespace.

Comment: How should I make sure that the class falls under App namespace? Can you please specify?

Comment: When I use this `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate` a line goes under `Current` and says  'Current' doesn't exist in the App context! How can I solve this?

Comment: If this class is inside of a .cs file, just make sure it is inside the curly braces for `namespace myAppname` and you should be fine.

Comment: What .net version and are you using a console app or windows app? Is this a WPF or UWP app?

Comment: it is WPF application

Comment: Then it should be working. Where is class located in your application?

Comment: Take a look at this. this is how the class is located! [IMG](https://ibb.co/dZu8up)

Comment: @E.Mamaghani Also post the top portion of your app.xaml.cs code.

Comment: I have created another class exactly same with the last one and it now accepts and works fine! don't know really why the last class had problem!

Comment: @E.Mamaghani You may still want to compare the files to see what is different for your own future reference. Please mark the answer as accepted also.