# C++/CX: Using Dispatcher to access UI thread doesn't work

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I am working on a UWP application and need to use TextBlock class in non-UI code. Attempting to instantiate TextBlock object produces "RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD (The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread)" exception.
From the information I have gathered on the Internet I understand that I should execute my code in the UI thread. I used the following code:

```
CoreDispatcher^ dispatcher = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Dispatcher;

dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new DispatchedHandler
                                                            [/* captured variables */]() {
    TextBlock ^text_block = ref new TextBlock();
    /* other code */
});
```

The problem is, I recieve the same exception the moment TextBlock instantiation is attempted. What am i doing wrong?

**UPD**:
I've just realized that the project I'm working on is a DirectX UWP App. Does it mean that it can't access UI thread directly?

Comment: Does the UWP app you are building have multiple windows open? And where are you running this code?

Comment: GetForCurrentThread() is not what you want.  Google "uwp get dispatcher", first hit is good.

Comment: @HansPassant I haven't found any other solution related to **C++**

Comment: @MartinZikmund from what I can tell it only has one window open. I am running it on Windows 10 Simulator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686729/17034

Answer (score 2):

Getting `CoreWindow` from `CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()` will only work when called from a UI thread which has an associated window. Instead, when you are on a background thread, you must access the UI thread differently:

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(
        CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal,
        ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this]()
{
   TextBlock ^text_block = ref new TextBlock();
   /* other code */
}));
```

This instead finds the `CoreWindow` of main view of your app and gets the its dispatcher. The advantage is that this approach doesn't use `GetForCurrentThread` so you can use it even from a background thread.

This becomes a problem when you have multiple views of your app open - then **each view has its own UI thread**, hence you must know which view is this action modifying so that you know which dispatcher you want to use. In this scenario, you can use the `CoreApplication::Views` collection to enumerate and access all application views.

Comment: Sadly I'm still getting the same exception when using your code sample.

Comment: Aren't you trying to run this from a Background Task?

Comment: No, it's happening in the same process with the main function, just in a different thread.