# "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread" when creating MenuFlyout

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, microsoft-metro

I am having this error when creating a new instance of MenuFlyout.I searched for a bit but couldn't find anything.Code is simple :

```
var tmpFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
```

I tried creating this instance from a different thread but that didn't help either , still got the exception.In which cases this exception will pop-up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245512/exception-the-application-called-an-interface-that-was-marshalled-for-a-differe)

> The problem is that your event handler doesn't execute on the UI
>   thread. I think the best way to fix that is to convert your EAP
>   (Event-based Asynchronous Pattern) method to TAP (Task-based
>   Asynchronous Pattern) using TaskCompletionSource:

Maybe that helps you out

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher.RunAsync solved the problem.

I tried with Task.Run method but problem persisted.As suggested , I did with RunAsync and problem solved.