# Error with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: asynchronous, windows-store-apps, sharepoint-2013, windows

I am trying to add an item to a sharepoint list but when i try to save  my changes im getting this error with my **Dispatcher.BeginInvoke** 'Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInvoke' and no extension method 'BeginInvoke' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
 ctx.BeginSaveChanges(
  (IAsyncResult result) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      () => ctx.EndSaveChanges(result)),
   ctx
```

);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579027/run-code-on-ui-thread-in-winrt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use the following instead:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
}
```