# c# BeginInvoke Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, linq-to-twitter

I dont understand this programming syntax around `Dispatcher.RunAsync`.

All I know is that I have to translate the following authentification module from [Linq2Twitter](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/blob/master/New/Demos/Linq2TwitterDemos_WindowsPhone/OAuth.xaml.cs) working on WP8 to WP8.1.

```
async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pinAuth = new PinAuthorizer
    {
        // Get the ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret for your app and load them here.
        CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
        {
            ConsumerKey = "",
            ConsumerSecret = ""
        },
        // Note: GetPin isn't used here because we've broken the authorization
        // process into two parts: begin and complete
        GoToTwitterAuthorization = pageLink => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            () => OAuthWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(pageLink, UriKind.Absolute)))
    };

    await pinAuth.BeginAuthorizeAsync();
}
```

The problem is `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

I found the solution for the problem in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211044/error-with-dispatcher-begininvoke) but I don't get it working with my programming skills.

I would also appreciate a link/video tutorial to this topic. I don't even know where to start learning about Dispatcher, Threading etc.

Cheers,

Chris

//Update

The following seems to work but I dont know how to retrieve the PIN value from this  `WebAuthenticationBroker`

```
            pinAuth = new PinAuthorizer
        {
            // Get the ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret for your app and load them here.
            CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = "",
                ConsumerSecret = ""
            },
            // Note: GetPin isn't used here because we've broken the authorization
            // process into two parts: begin and complete
            GoToTwitterAuthorization = async pageLink => 
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
               () => { WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(
                    new Uri(pageLink, UriKind.Absolute)); })
        };

        await pinAuth.BeginAuthorizeAsync();
```

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is not available in WinRT based WP8.1 Apps. You can get a Dispatcher using CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579027/run-code-on-ui-thread-in-winrt

Comment: Thank You. Sounds similiar to the solution I've linked in the question and therefore I'm still not able to do the transfer from this line of code:
GoToTwitterAuthorization = pageLink => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            () => OAuthWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(pageLink, UriKind.Absolute)))
to the WinRT format...

Comment: I'd say if you get the dispatcher as described in those links from CoreWindow the line should translate to:
GoToTwitterAuthorization = pageLink => await dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
  OAuthWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(pageLink, UriKind.Absolute));
});

Comment: updated my question @OliverUlm Thank You