# Windows Phone Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

My Windows Runtime Application reads a NDEF NFC-Tag. 
When the App reads the NFC-Tag correct my method `message received`will open.

```
private void messageReceived(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
{
    device.StopSubscribingForMessage(NFCID);
    var ndefMessage = NdefMessage.FromByteArray(message.Data.ToArray());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (NdefRecord record in ndefMessage) sb.AppendLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(record.Payload, 0, record.Payload.Length));

    String data= sb.ToString();
    ShowData(data);
} 

private void ShowData(string data)
{
    tbx.Text = data;
}
```

When I want to set this data to a textfield, every time a exception is thrown:
**Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to dispatch it first:

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            tbx.Text = data;
        });
```

EDIT: Obviously this is not always the best solution. Do it this way instead if you still receive that error: [Run code on UI thread in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579027/run-code-on-ui-thread-in-winrt)