# Show MessageDialog from app.xaml.cs in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Im trying to show a message to the user when connection to the internet is lost

I have this method on my `App.xaml.cs`

```
static async void NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged(object sender)
    {

        //Get the Internet connection profile
        //ConnectionProfile connectionProfileInfo = null;
        try
        {
            ConnectionProfile InternetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

            if (InternetConnectionProfile == null)
            {
                ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["INTERNET"] = false;

                ShowBox("Internet Lost");

                Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
            }
            else
            {
                ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["INTERNET"] = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unexpected exception occurred: " + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

and this other one

```
public async static void ShowBox(string msg)
    {
        try
        {

            await new MessageDialog(msg, "No Internet").ShowAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

When i cause a connection lost ( disable my internet connection ) the ShowBox method gets called, and i get this exception on it:

> > Invalid window handle.
>
> This API must be called from a thread with a CoreWindow or a window
>   must have been set explicitly.

Is there any way to show a MessageDialog from that event?

Comment: Sounds like its expecting you to do this in the UI thread. Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17315187/1565402

Comment: Ah nice, dind't found that post, thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run code on UI thread in WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579027/run-code-on-ui-thread-in-winrt)

Answer (score 3):

[image]Try to add this:

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    MessageDialog msg= new MessageDialog("No Internet");
    msg.ShowAsync();
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Manuel Patrone answer is almost correct. just small fix for his answer.

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
async() =>
{
    MessageDialog msg= new MessageDialog("No Internet");
    await msg.ShowAsync();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running through the Desktop Bridge ensure that you're initializing your store context properly. See [Using the StoreContext class with the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#using-the-storecontext-class-with-the-desktop-bridge) for more information about it.