# UWP bitmapimage on background thread

Tags: multithreading, win-universal-app, bitmapimage, background-thread

I have a simple question.
In my UWP app I am using multiple threads and while on a background thread when i try to create a simple BitmapImage by using code: `var image=new BitmapImage();`. It throws an exception

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

this exception occurs on the very line where I try to create the image. I simply want to create this image, deal with its properties and then store it in my datalist.

**Note**: datalist is a simple public static property which is accesible throughout the app. thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the full context from the question, so I am not sure why this exception is bubbling up, but one sure way to fix it is using [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx).
The documentation says:

> If you are on a worker thread and want to schedule work on the UI thread, use CoreDispatcher::RunAsync.

If you are using [MVVMLight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/), you can also make use of it's DispatcherHelper class' [CheckBeginInvokeOnUI](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/eb4d9f1b-243b-d44c-aa83-2ab60d21d85d.htm) method. It's a bit better, since it first checks which thread it is called on and if it's the UI thread, it executes the action immediately and passes it to the UI thread only if needed.

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer if it solves your problem! ;)

Comment: Your answer really helped me to find the exact answer for UWP, here it is
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10594388/5305863